# Using Motorola Symbol barcode scanner in Simple COM Port Emulation on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a Motorola Symbol DS6708 barcode scanner.  I need to scan QR codes that are in binary.  So, the default HID Keyboard Emulation mode will not work for me.  I want to put the device into a serial device mode.  I can put it into Simple COM Port Emulation mode, and the device appears on the USB bus.  However, it doesn't appear as a serial device, and there's nothing in /dev that relates to the device.

The documentation refers to a driver for COM mode for Windows, but I don't see any drivers for Mac.  Any tips to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Check around and see if you can figure it who manufactures the USB->serial chip in the device.   If it is Prolific, there are open source Prolific drivers available for the Mac.    If the bridge is TI, then see if you can suss out the model of the chip, since there is example source for drivers (compilable) available thought the TI developer program/portal.